# How do you define class variables accessible by all instances

Tags: python

I want to define a array with class-wide scope/access by all instances. Example module (bc.py):

```
class B:
    glist = []  # array common to all instances

    def __init__(self, number):
        glist.append(number)                                                                                                            

    def printCurrentList():
        print ('Current List:', glist)

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        b1 = B(7)
        b2 = B(2)
        b3 = B(8)

    def printNow(self):
        B.printCurrentList()
```

I am calling this from file a.py, as:

```
from bc import C                                                                                                                        
C().printNow()
```

Getting error as:

```
python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 2, in <module>
    C().printNow()
  File "/Users/manidipsengupta/pytorials/bc.py", line 16, in __init__
    b1 = B(7)
  File "/Users/manidipsengupta/pytorials/bc.py", line 7, in __init__
    glist.append(number)
NameError: name 'glist' is not defined
```

What should be the correct syntax for this? Thank you.

Comment: `class C` is not a subclass of `class B`, therefore instances of `C` would have to use `B.glist` to access the class attribute. Methods of (only) class `B` can reference the attribute as `self.glist` (or they can also use `B.glist` but that would make them unsuitable for use in subclasses of it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either

```
B.glist.append(number)
```

or

```
self.glist.append(number)
```

will work. I'd prefer the former as it better shows that `glist` is a static class variable, instead of per instance.

Answer (score 1):

You have access class variables through class or instance:

```
class B:
    glist = []  # array common to all instances

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.glist.append(number)                                                                                                            

    @classmethod
    def printCurrentList(cls):
        print ('Current List:', cls.glist)
```